# Feeding a tensorflow placeholder from an array

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to train CatPole-v0 using Q learning. When trying to update the replay buffer with experience I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

The related code snippet is:

```
def update_replay_buffer(replay_buffer, state, action, reward, next_state, done, action_dim):
    # append to buffer
    experience = (state, action, reward, next_state, done)
    replay_buffer.append(experience)
    # Ensure replay_buffer doesn't grow larger than REPLAY_SIZE
    if len(replay_buffer) > REPLAY_SIZE:
        replay_buffer.pop(0)
    return None
```

The placeholder to be fed is

```
action_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, action_dim])
```

Can someone clarify how action_dim should be used to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by `action_in`:

```
action_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, action_dim])
```

This means that `action_in` can have shape like `(None, action_dim)`, nothing other than that. And from the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

From error it seems your `action_dim` is `2`.
its easy to see that you're placing an object of shape `(128,)` in place of tensor which expects shape like `(?, 2)` i.e `(None, 2)`.

So you need to check your `feed_dict` that's where you're messing. Your placeholder `action_in`'s dimensions should match with object you're putting in `feed_dict`.

> Can someone clarify how action_dim should be used to resolve this
>   error?

Seems your environment's action has two components from value of `action_dim`, but you are providing only `one` component, this is inferred from your error(`(128,)`). You need to fix this. Hope this helps.